# how do I sign my iOS app out of facebook - like REALLY sign out. iOS devices use Safari cookie that my app cannot forget

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sdk

I have searched high and low and spent 8 hours on this one item alone trying out loads of suggestions here. There are many people stuck on this and other forums. Here is another way of asking this question - as some people seemed to say it worked, others didn't - i think they were using an older version of the facebook SDK.

I want my app to ask for facebook credentials everytime for one feature. Instead what is happening is that the delegate (ios facebook app or ios Safari) is remembering that I am logged in and telling my app - "go for it". I don't want that. Log out dangit and forget my app!

Upon logout, using Facebook SDK 3.1, I have cycled through my shared cookies as lots of posts tell me - some poeple said thanks it worked, others said it didn't. I HAVE NO COOKIES - the for next loop indicates non whether filtered or not.

If I force things to Safari for auth and then reset Safari in General->Settings - it will ask for credentials. This is what I want everytime without having to go to General->Settings.

So
a) how can i use my own UIWebView - this would get those cookies working - but I don't think this is how facebook sign on works using the api
b) how do I get a hold of those cookies in Safari from my app?
c) how did someone else get this working?

I cannot get access to facebook.m - or if so - how did you? I think that was a prior sdk which a had a hack to a couple of lines. I am using the framework download.

If this doesn't work, I will have them log into a Facebook php page with a session that I can control

Comment: Have you tried -closeAndClearTokenInformation on your session?

Answer (score 2):

I'm unclear about whether you are using the iOS Facebook feature, but assuming iOS6+ - Have you tried using `ACAccountStore` and the `removeAccount:withCompletionHandler: method?`

The full reference is [ACAccountStore Class Reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)